# Deleting a session/structure with coldfusion

Tags: session, coldfusion, struts

I have a session which is a collection of structures

## SESSION.squad.achievements[key]

so it may be

```
SESSION.squad.achievements[2010] = "swam the english channel";
SESSION.squad.achievements[2009] = "ran a marathon";
SESSION.squad.achievements[2008] = "cycled Le Tour";
```

My code deletes the stucture temporarily, but does not delete the session so when I refresh the value still exists

```
<cfset myYear = #myYear# />
<cfset #StructDelete(SESSION.squad.achievements, myYear)#>
```

Any ideas how I can delete this value?

Comment: Can you specify which value you want to be deleted? Here your code should remove, for year=2010, the value SESSION.squad.achievements[2010] = "swam the english channel" no?

Comment: Also, how are you testing that the value has been deleted? It may be that you're refresh action is causing the value to be set again... Dump the session before and after your delete statement so that you can see if it was actually removed. Also, verify the value of myYear as `<cfset myYear = #myYear# />` doesn't look correct at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using cflock

```
<cflock timeout="30" throwontimeout="No" type="EXCLUSIVE" scope="SESSION">
    <cfset StructDelete(SESSION.squad.achievements, myYear)>
</cflock>
```

Comment: Ross or Lucas, How does this solve the problem? Confusing question to begin with becuase it doesn't have enough information, but I don't see how a cflock does anything useful in this situation.

Comment: the deleting code is called via jquery/ajax, the value #myYear# is passed via post. I have never used cflock before but it seems to lock the code so the value gets deleted before it the page is refreshed. My code looked fine before using it, maybe Lucas knows more about how <CFLOCK> works. A bit about it on Ben Nadel's site - http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1123-CFLock-And-Negative-Outcomes-Think-It-Through.htm

Comment: Actually reading about it seems like a bit of a hack, probably what I need to so is do some error checking to make sure the session strut is deleted before calling the refresh. It works for now but will come back to it for a more solid solution